# Batch calling every .bat file in a specific folder?

Tags: batch-file

I've tried seaching this forum... but every time i run an example script it says "device isn't ready... or something like that".
How do i call every existing .bat file in a specific directory?
I want it to call every .bat file.
Thank You!

Comment: Without showing your code it is quite hard to tell what causes the errors you mention... Take a look at the `for` command (type `for /?` in command prompt for details) and the `call` command (type `call /?`). If you need the batch files to run in a specific order, or if you want them to run simultaneously, you need to specify that. Please put all additional information into the question by editing your post rather than placing comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the batch files running sequentially, in alphabetical order, you can loop through a list of bat files in a specified folder, and `call` each one.

```
set "BatFolder=c:\whatever\your\specific\directory\is"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b %BatFolder%\*.bat') do (
    call "%%a"
)
```

Depending on your expectations and the needs of your batch files, instead of `call`, you might use `start`, `cmd`, or `runas` with their appropriate switches.